# Storing dataframe automatically converts character into numeric. How to stop this?

Tags: r, dataframe

My data looks a bit like:

```
dummy.from <- data.frame(SetID = rep(c(104:109), times=4), Name = rep(c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"), each=6), Value=sample(c(1:100,0.5), 24) )
```

So:

```
    SetID Name Value
1    104   A1    82
2    105   A1    79
3    106   A1    54
4    107   A1    87
5    108   A1    62
6    109   A1    28
7    104   A2    37
8    105   A2    72
9    106   A2   100
10   107   A2    64
11   108   A2    14
...
```

Basically, what I want to do is to transfer part of the data to another data frame, based on another value (not shown) calculated separately for each `SetID`.

For that I use a for loop like:

```
dummy.to <- data.frame(SetID=numeric(0), Name=character(0), value=numeric(0), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for(i in 104:109){
  dummy.to[(nrow(dummy.to)+1):(nrow(dummy.to)+4),] <- dummy.from[dummy.from$SetID==i,]
}
```

The problem that I encounter is that just looking at the latter part of the code `(dummy.from[dummy.from$SetID==i,])` is just the way I want it to be stored, when I then look at dummy.to, for some reason the Name column has been converted to numbers like this:

```
> dummy.to
   SetID Name value
1    104    1    82
7    104    2    37
13   104    3    52
19   104    4    73
2    105    1    79
8    105    2    72
14   105    3    91
....
```

Although strangely, when looking at the structure (`str(dummy)`), the Name column is still of type character.
I'm really confused about this, as I'd like my names to show up as they were in the original data.frame. 
I know I could just create a loop to change the names back, but I'm wondering if there's something that I'm overlooking in the code which could be causing this behaviour.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try adding `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to your `dummy.from` call.  What's happening is your `Name` vector is actually a factor, not a character string.  They get treated a bit differently, and your factors are being converted to the underlying numeric code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data.frame auto sets any strings to factors. You want to change that.

```
dummy.from <- data.frame(SetID = rep(c(104:109), times=4), Name = rep(c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"), each=6), Value=sample(c(1:100,0.5), 24) )
str(dummy.from)
'data.frame':   24 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ SetID: int  104 105 106 107 108 109 104 105 106 107 ...
 $ Name : Factor w/ 4 levels "A1","A2","A3",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Value: num  37 9 69 38 93 71 91 34 86 51 ...
```

Here's what you want

```
dummy.from <- data.frame(SetID = rep(c(104:109), times=4), Name = rep(c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"), each=6), Value=sample(c(1:100,0.5), 24), stringsAsFactors = F) #your desired output just requires stringsAsFactors = F
> str(dummy.from)
'data.frame':   24 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ SetID: int  104 105 106 107 108 109 104 105 106 107 ...
 $ Name : chr  "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" ...
 $ Value: num  80 46 61 52 38 9 7 59 15 56 ...
```

Comment: That does seem to solve the problem - thanks for the speedy reply!

Just wondering though, is it possible to add something to the loop that will allow the transfer of the factor names? Since otherwise, I'll have to add stringsAsFactors everytime I transfer the data (which I seem to find myself doing a lot), which just appears a bit error-prone to me.

Comment: A few things on that. 1. per @nsm's comment, I don't believe you need a loop here. You can actually just subset the data. 2. you only need to add stringsAsFactors in the initial setup. 3. if you really hate it THAT much, just write a new data.frame function - `data.frame2<-function(...) return(data.frame(stringsAsFactors=F,...))`

Comment: At the start of your script, you can add `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`, which will prevent the strings from ever being forced to factors when you read in your data (assuming you're reading it in, not importing an .Rdata file).

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is sorting the data frame by the "SetID" column. There is a function for that called `order`

```
dummy.from[order(dummy.from$SetID),]
```

Or using the devel version of  `data.table` you can order you data *by reference*. Link here: [Installation: data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
library(data.table) ## v 1.9.5+
setorder(dummy.from, SetID)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understood what you need to do but it seems, in first place, that you don't need any `for` loop, Insted, to obtain the result you need:

```
dummy.to <- dummy.from[dummy.from$SetID==104:109,]
```

The problem you mentioned about thwe types is because the Name column in dummy.from is not character but numeric, because it is a factor.

Comment: Thanks for your response!

The reason why I need the for-loop is because my original data-set is quite a lot bigger and contains another few variables by which I decide which rows I actually want to use. The decision is made on a case-by-case basis for each SetID. 

You were right about the Name column being a factor - I completely overlooked that. Do you by any chance know if there's a way to faithfully transfer the factor names in a similar way without altering the structure of the dummy.from dataset?

Comment: @Liz that won't be an issue. If I wanted to subset the data on the column 'fruits'='apples' and 'names' = 'Liz' and 'number'>1, I could simply do the following: `df[df$fruits=='apples' & df$names='Liz' & df$number>1,]`

Comment: @Jason, yep, you are right if I wanted to look for a consistent variable. In my case, though, it's more like this: given a data.frame with columns SetID, Name, Value and Colour, for each SetID, calculate the mean value for each colour, then choose the colour with the highest mean value and add the entries of that colour to the final data frame. I hope this makes sense, and if you have a better way to do this other than a for loop, I'm very happy to take suggestions!